# firestore is not storing data as it show me a msg:'Register Successfully' but don't store data in firestore

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore

I'm doing role based authentication in firebase authentication and using firestore to store user information. What's my registration's activity is doing is:getting information from user and authenticate email,password using firebase authentication and and other information including role,name, are storing in firestore when i run the app it show me msg of registered successfully and in authentication[users] it show gmail of users who entered but firestore does not contain any data,it shows nothing what to do,,I want when user registerd, a node is automatically created and data of user is stored in firestore and when i open firestore it show me data of all users.[how to do it]

```
private FirebaseFirestore db;
db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
void createAccount() {
  String name = nameEditText.getText().toString();
  String email = emailEditText.getText().toString();
  String password = passwordEditText.getText().toString();
  int selectedRadioButtonId = roleRadioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
  RadioButton selectedRadioButton = findViewById(selectedRadioButtonId);

  if (selectedRadioButton != null) {
    selectedRole = selectedRadioButton.getText().toString();
    Toast.makeText(this, "Selected Role: " + selectedRole, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  } else {
    selectedRole = "Role"; // Default value
  }
  boolean isValidated = validateData(name, email, password, selectedRole);
  if (!isValidated) {
    return;
  }
  createAccountInFirebase(email, password, name, selectedRole);
}
void createAccountInFirebase(String email, String password, String name, String role) {
  changeInProgress(true);
  FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
  firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener\ < AuthResult\ > () {
      @Override
      public void onComplete(@NonNull com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task\ < AuthResult\ > task) {
        changeInProgress(false);
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
          Toast.makeText(Registration.this, "Successfully created account", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().sendEmailVerification();
          String uid = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
          DocumentReference userDocumentRef = db.collection("users").document(uid);

          User user = new User(name, email, role);
          userDocumentRef.set(user)
            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener\ < Void\ > () {
              @Override
              public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                finish();
              }
            })
            .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
              @Override
              public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(Registration.this, "Firestore data write   failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
              }
            });
          firebaseAuth.signOut();
        } else {
          Toast.makeText(Registration.this, task.getException().getLocalizedMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
      }
    });
}
```

Firestore rules:

```json
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=\*\*} {
      allow read: if request.auth != null;
    }
    match /users/{userId} {
      allow create: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == userId;
      allow read, update, delete: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == userId;
    }
  }
}
```

Here is user model class

```
public class User {
  private String name;
  private String email;
  private String role;
  public User() {}
  public User(String name, String email, String role) {
    this.name = name;
    this.email = email;
    this.role = role;
  }
  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }
  public String getEmail() {
    return email;
  }
  public String getRole() {
    return role;
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.
What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors? Please also format the code so it can be more understandable.

Comment: I want to create role-based authentication system.The code i've provided is expected to create account having fields:name,email,password,role. using firebase authentication and cloud firestore. the firebase authentication checks only email password and show message 'Registered Successfully',I wish the user_id firebase authentication generate should be used by firestore to store the data[name.email,role] of same user but firestore does not store the data.On the basis of role selected the user is redirected to appropriate dashboard like if admin logged in he must goes to admin dashboard etc.

Comment: Is any of the failure listeners called?

Comment: In my testing, the code inside the if statement consistently runs, which means that the registration process is generally successful. I have not observed any scenarios where the failure listener is executed. It appears that user registration is proceeding without encountering any issues related to email or password validation. But it still does not store user's name,role,email in firestore.

Comment: So when you call `.set(user)`, which listener is called?